# Partial, Layout, Template rendering problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, layout, yield, partials

### The Situation

So when I visit a page, I want to be able to apply a layout to a partial (I have three partials that I want with the same layout). Right now, I am trying to do it with this command:

```
<%= render :partial => "shared/services/essay", :layout => "layouts/services/tab_pane", :locals => { :service => "essay" } %>
```

where `shared/services/essay` goes something like:

```
<% content_for :intro do %>
<p>
    blah.
</p>
<% end %>

<% content_for :workflow do %>
<div>
    blah.
</div>
<% end %>

<% content_for :value_prop do %>
<p>
    blah.
</p>
<% end %>
```

and `layouts/services/tab_pane' goes like:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in" id=<%= service %> >
    <%= yield :intro %>

    <div class="span7 workflow">
        <h3>Workflow</h3>
        <%= yield :workflow %>
    </div>

    <div class="span5 value-proposition">
        <h3>Our Value Proposition for You</h3>
        <%= yield :value_prop %>
        <div class="call-to-action">
            <%= link_to "Action!", contact_path, class: "btn btn-large btn-warning" %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### The Problem

When I load it up, I just get the layout HTML. None of the content is put through. So essentially, the yields aren't pulling in content or something.

Could someone help? Thanks!

### Things I've tried

If I try nested layouts as mentioned on Ruby Guides (adding...

```
<%= render :template => "layouts/services/tab_pane", :locals  => { :service => "essay" } %>
```

to my partials and making all the proper name changes), my second partial contains content from the first, and my third from both the first and second. So my second partial would contain 2 blah's for each section and my third partial would contain 3 blah's for each section. Thanks!

## UPDATE:

The problem is now solved (thanks Michael), but now I guess I was wondering what best practices were when dealing with something like this. Should I avoid something like this in the future and only worry about giving templates/layout to whole pages as opposed to partials within the page? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder if you are getting hit with the ViewFlow handling of partials.  Are you calling this partial several times?  The problem is rails stores the content_for data in a hash and its non-destructive.

You could try adding:

`def yield_content!(content_key)
  view_flow.content.delete(content_key)
end`

in your ApplicationHelper and call yield_content instead of yield in your layout file.

Comment: thanks for response! so... i tried adding what you said into ApplicationHelper, reloading the localhost server, but whenever i try to load the page now, i get a `undefined method "yield_content" for #<#<Class:0x007f860f93ca00>:0x007f860f910838>`.

Comment: oh ok. i fixed that problem. i had to call `yield_content!` instead of just `yield_content` because i had `yield_content!` in my ApplicationHelper. so it works now! but do you know of any better practices for trying to do what i did? i feel like overriding the way ViewFlow works may not the best way to do this... thanks!

Comment: Its a matter of how rails works, not sure if there is a better way, but you could avoid layouts in your partials ;)