# Render a partial with layout passing two blocks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, partials

I have a page where I need to render a block of html code different times that has always the same structure but different content.
I thought to extract the structure in a layout and make different partials, rendering them with the same layout.

Main Page

```
<body>
  <%= render partial: 'a', :layout => "layouts/card"%>
  <%= render partial: 'b', :layout => "layouts/card"%>
  <%= render partial: 'c', :layout => "layouts/card"%>
</body>
```

The layout 'layouts/card' is like that:

> ```
> <div class="slide red">   
>  <div class="row full-width">
>     <div class="large-3 columns">
>       <%= yield :content_a %>
>     </div>
>  </div>
>  <div class="large-9 columns">
>     <%= yield :content_b%>
>  </div>
> </div>
> ```

The partial 'a' is like that:

```
<% content_for :content_a do %>
 <div>
  <div>
   Hello A
  </div>
    Hello A2
 </div>
<%end%>
<% content_for :content_b do %>
 <div>
  <div>
   Hello B
  </div>
    Hello B2
 </div>
 <img src="..."/>
<%end%>
```

Partial b has different content for both and is so variable so I can't pass thousands of parameters

But doesn't really work and render the layout without content in none of the two yield fileds.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think your yield statement on the layout is getting processes first before the content_for. In that case yield will be replaced with nothing. I am not sure if there is a solution for this.

What if you change your logic to something like below since you are just trying to DRY up your code and its not actually a layout:

_a.html.erb

```
<div class="slide red">   
 <div class="row full-width">
    <div class="large-3 columns">
      <%= content_a%>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="large-9 columns">
    <%= content_b%>
 </div>
</div>
```

Main Page

```
<body>
  <%= render partial: 'a', :locals => {:content_a => "Hello A", :content_b => "Hello B"}%>
  <%= render partial: 'a', :locals => {:content_a => "Hello C", :content_b => "Hello D"}%>
  <%= render partial: 'a', :locals => {:content_a => "Hello E", :content_b => "Hello F"}%>
</body>
```

Comment: The problem is that the code is composed by a block of HTML. I edit the question to be more clear

Comment: Found this post that could help you -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106580/partial-layout-template-rendering-problems

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
 <%= render partial: 'a', :layout => "layouts/card"%>
```